# Injected Font-Awesome icons to the DOM with Javascript do not display until page refresh

Tags: javascript, dom, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm configuring a page using Javascript to select and inject different icons depending upon JSON data. Sometimes one or more of the injected icons does not appear until the page has been refreshed. I'm finding Firefox fails on all icons, but Chrome is ok after a refresh.

If I inspect the DOM I can see the missing elements are in the HTML as

```
<i id="live-icon" class="fas fa-check fa-2x"></i>
```

Whereas the working elements are shown as

```
<svg id="airdrop-icon" class="svg-inline--fa fa-times-circle fa-w-16 fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="times-circle" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M256 8C119 8 8 119 8 256s111 248 248 248 248-111 248-248S393 8 256 8zm121.6 313.1c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17L338 377.6c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L256 312l-65.1 65.6c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L134.4 338c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17l65.6-65-65.6-65.1c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17l39.6-39.6c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l65 65.7 65.1-65.6c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l39.6 39.6c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17L312 256l65.6 65.1z"></path></svg>
<!-- <i id="airdrop-icon" class="fas fa-times-circle fa-2x"></i> -->
```

So it looks like my DOM injection worked, but font-awesome isn't expanding it to the svg. Is this a possible timing issue?

I've tried running with both the CDN version of font-awesome (js and css) and local to see if that was possibly the issue, but it's not.

Javascript snippet

```js
const liveIcon = 'fas fa-check fa-2x';
const notLiveIcon = 'fas fa-times-circle fa-2x';
const liveColor = 'green';
const notLiveColor = 'red'

function SetElementIconById(id, icon) {

  const i = document.getElementById(id);
  i.setAttribute('class', icon);
}

function SetElementColorById(id, color) {
  const span = document.getElementById(id);
  const bg = document.getElementById(id);
  bg.setAttribute('class', bg.getAttribute('class') + ' ' + color);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  SetElementColorById('live-color', liveColor);
  SetElementColorById('live-body-color', liveColor + " darken-2")
  SetElementIconById('live-icon', liveIcon);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- Live -->
<div class="col s12 m6 l4">
  <div id="live-color" class="card white-text hoverable tooltipped center-align" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Live date">
    <div class="card-content vtiny">
      <h5 style="font-weight: 300"><i class="fas fa-heartbeat fa-sm"></i> Live</h5>
    </div>
    <div id="live-body-color" class="card-content vtiny">
      <p><i id="live-icon"></i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "fa fa-heartbeat..." instead of "fas" ?

Comment: <i class="fas fa-heartbeat"></i> taken from the site https://fontawesome.com/icons/heartbeat?style=solid

Comment: Oh okay, my bad, I was still on FA 4. If you put an icon into your html (not by javascript; in the html source code), is it shown ?

Comment: Yes, it's only icons injected into the DOM that are having problems.

Comment: I went through the documentation, and the thing is that when the page is loaded, FA 5 replaces all the icons with an SVG equivalent. As such, you need to find a way either to convert the i tag into its svg or to add directly the svg. Maybe what you could do is have the icon you want to add in the source html, but with display: hidden; and then copy the svg to the right place when you need it ?

Comment: That makes sense, I'm trying to think if it'll work in the long run, as in: do I know all the possible icons, or is the dynamic json data going to start carrying some of that information too. I can see the latter potentially happening thanks to the brand icons that font-awesome is providing, but for the standard stuff, checks, crosses, calendar icons, they could all be pre-loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fa SVG symbols.

In your page :

```
<i data-fa-symbol="delete" class="fas fa-trash fa-fw"></i>
```

The image is loaded and translated into svg that can be reused anywhere in the page (HTML or JS).

Then you can use it wether in your page like that (to avoid multiple execution of the javascript code that translate it to svg) :

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>
```

And you can use it on your javascript like that (here with jQuery) :

```
$("#selector").append('<svg><use xlink:href="#delete"></use></svg>Remove');
```

For more information please check the [official documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-symbols)